# 4K (3840x2160) with GeForce GT 730M (Notebook Acer v3-571g) on HDMI port not working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I have a notebook Acer v3-571g with a GeForce GT 730M and try to get my new Samsung UHD Monitor 28" "U28D590D" to work in a 4K resolution via HDMI.

As I can see on http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-730m/specifications the resolution should be supported. As the notebook is from 2012 I suppose the HDMI-version should support this as well.

```
lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
```

I tried the following graphic drivers:

- nvidia-331
- nvidia-331-updates
- nvidia-346
- nvidia-340
- nvidia-349
- xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

After working through numerous threads I tried to add the resolution by the following command (tried different settings as well):

```
gtf 3840 2160 30
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00" 339.57  3840 4080 4496 5152  2160 2161 2164 2197  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "3840x2160_30.00"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "3840x2160_30.00"
```

The monitor should support this resolution via HDMI with 30hz.

Using the propritary nvidia drivers, I notice that nvidia-settings does not detect two monitors, the ubuntu display tool does, but it only offers resolutions up to 1920x1080 (which works).

This experience reminds me of trying to get wireless to work on Ubuntu 5.04. Is it too early to use 4k on Ubuntu?

I'd be thankful for any hints. I'm wondering if this is a software problem or whether my hardware is not sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a HDMI cable compatible with 4K (HDMI 1.4a if I am correct)? And do you have a dual-boot with Windows to be able to make sure this is a Ubuntu issue?

Comment: I'm using the cable which came with the monitor, that must be compatible I guess. At the moment I don't have windows installed, I'm afraid, but I've been thinking about it.

Comment: Also with windows 8 and the latest drivers I can't make it work. The highest available resolution is 1920x1080. If I try to manually set it to 4k and 30hz, I get the message that this bandwith is not supported. Only in interlaced mode I can even set it to those values but don't get a usable picture. Maybe it's a hardware limitation after all or this hybrid graphic card is making trouble. The nvidia should support HDMI 1.4a, though.

Comment: In that case, you may want to ask this on SuperUser.com instead.

Comment: Thanks, here is my question on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/902474/4k-3840x2160-with-geforce-gt-730m-notebook-acer-v3-571g-on-hdmi-port-not-wor

Answer (score 1):

4k resolutions are only supported in the HDMI spec at 30hz officially, most monitors and graphics cards will stick to the spec by default.

However 30hz is not nice , it feels laggy and slow to use.

I've had some luck using cvt to generate custom modelines which pushed the refresh up to 44hz which seemed to be a sweet spot in terms of being the most my graphics card (intel 4000 + GeForce GT 750M in optimus) could output reliably. It will take around 10 to 20 seconds to sync and if you have the refresh rate too high the screen will periodically blank and resync. If it doesn't work it will not damage your monitor like the old CRT's did so experiment away. I was able to get 44hz to stay synced solidly all day.

The cable that came with my monitor could not handle this but the 'amazon basics high speed hdmi with ethernet' cable i bought for a few quid could so its worth trying a few cables if this isn't working straight away.

Heres the script i wrote for setting up my screen

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup my massive monitor at 45hz if its plugged in

RESOLUTION="3440 1440 44" 
OUTPUT="HDMI-0"

CONNECTED=$(xrandr --current | grep -i hdmi | cut -f2 -d' ')

if [ "$CONNECTED" = "connected" ]; then
    MODELINE=$(cvt $RESOLUTION | cut -f2 -d$'\n')
    MODEDATA=$(echo $MODELINE | cut -f 3- -d' ')
    MODENAME=$(echo $MODELINE | cut -f2 -d' ')

    echo "Adding mode - " $MODENAME $MODEDATA
    xrandr --newmode $MODENAME $MODEDATA
    xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 $MODENAME
    xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode $MODENAME
else
    echo "Monitor is not detected"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I can test this anymore because I got a new Notebook.